# Bind variable to Text property of RichTextBlock (which is inside a RichTextColumns)

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am trying to bind a variable to Text property of RichTextBlock but the content is not showing up.
RichTextBlock is inside a RichTextColumns element present in common folder.

My Xaml code :-

```
<Page
x:Class="Test_Menu.TopicDetailsPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test_Menu"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:common="using:Test_Menu.Common"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <!-- Content is allowed to flow across as many columns as needed -->
    <common:RichTextColumns x:Name="richTextColumns" >
        <RichTextBlock x:Name="richTextBlock" Width="300" Height="700" Style="{StaticResource ItemRichTextStyle}" IsTextSelectionEnabled="False" >
            <Paragraph>
                <Run FontWeight="Normal" Text="{Binding sTitle}" Foreground="White" />
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBlock>

        <!-- Additional columns are created from this template -->
        <common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RichTextBlockOverflow Width="450" Margin="80,0,0,0">
                    <RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="-1" Y="4"/>
                    </RichTextBlockOverflow.RenderTransform>
                </RichTextBlockOverflow>
            </DataTemplate>
        </common:RichTextColumns.ColumnTemplate>
    </common:RichTextColumns>

</Grid>
```

My Code behind -

```
namespace Test_Menu
```

{
 public sealed partial class TopicDetailsPage : Page
    {
        public string sTitle { get; set; }

```
    public TopicDetailsPage()
    {
        sTitle = "Test Text";
        this.InitializeComponent();
        richTextBlock.DataContext = sTitle; //name of richTextBlock

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

The out is coming as blank. Any help would highly be appreciated.